# Angular parent form-control Bootstrap / CSS is not applied to child component

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I created a autocomplete child component that I am using in parent. In parent when try to apply the validation using Bootstrap form-control it's not getting applied to this child component - which is an input box with a list, although it's getting applied to other controls which are not child.

Child component HTML:

```html
<div class="searching">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  (input)="getFilteredData(inputBox.value);" class="form-control"  [formControl]="inputBox">
  <div id="search" tabindex="0" >
    <ul class="suggestionList">
      <li  *ngFor="let result of filteredResults | async" (click)="onUserSelected(result)" >{{result[displayField1]}} | {{result[displayField2]}} {{result[displayField3]}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Parent component:

```html
<app-auto-complete formControlName="requestorId" 
                     [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && 
                     requestorId.errors }"></app-auto-complete>
                  <div *ngIf="submitted && f.requestorId.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                      <div *ngIf="f.requestorId.errors.required">Requestor ID is required</div>
                  </div>
```

Child CSS:

```css
.searching {
  width: inherit;
    position: relative;
}
      .searching input {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
      }
      .suggestionList {
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
      }
      .suggestionList li {
        list-style-type: none;
        border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
        cursor: pointer;
        left: 0;
        font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-size: 1em;
        text-align: left;
      }
```

Comment: To override style rule on the component style file, add this on your component.ts

`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`

Comment: Or try use ::ng-deep .searching if i understand your question correctly.

Comment: ::ng-deep .searching in child component css or in saas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several workaraounds in mind, so I hope any helps.

As mentioned in the comments, add in your parent component decorator the property 'encapsulation' (same level as 'selector' and such) with ViewEncapsulation.None.
Be aware that this approach makes styles of the parent component penetrate the whole app, so be wary with doing this unless you have the parent selector be really specific such as `.my-specific-parent-selector-which-isnt-gonna-be-repeated`

use @Input property on child component to pass the validation boolean, and apply the class directly according to the Input passed.

add a `.parent-selector .is-invalid` selector to parent, and then add behind it a `::ng-deep .parent-selector .is-invalid` making that specific styling penetrate child classes. Be wary that this approach is deprecated though, so it might stop working in the future (although unlikely)

Note:
also note that you are applying the `is-invalid` class to a selector.. if you inspect with chrome web browser you will see that this selector usually is a different element that where you try to add your class... so maybe your best approach is using inputs

Comment: I like the approach 2: use @Input property. Can you elaborate it further.

Comment: Sure!... if you add the @Input() decorator to a parameter on your child class (such as `@Input() invalid: boolean` then you can pass data to your child component through binding, from your parent component like so:

`<div class="parent-component"><child-comp [invalid]="parentBool"></child-comp></div>`

the same way that you pass things like [disabled] or so.. also, there's an output decorator to emit data to parent components you should also look at!...

if I wasn't clear enough please tell me to clarify. Happy coding!

Comment: but i have another question regarding the design pattern. I have @input and @output property both in parent and child component ,is there a better way to design it. there are 2-3  back-forth events(Event emiter) need to be fired from parent to child and then child to parent . ` in parent: private autoFocusLost: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();,  and then in child: @Output() selectionChanged: EventEmitter<any> =   new EventEmitter();
  @Output() inputEdited: EventEmitter<any> =   new EventEmitter(); `

Comment: This means your implementation has components inside compoents and I believe that is fine. I could be wrong though and somebody could enlighten me. If they are smart components though, you could create a service that manages those values and inject them in the grand child component. If they are dumb components this is not doable though I think, or at least not preferable.

Comment: u mean creating a shared service  between parent and child component.Both are reading/updating value in this service?